# Are there any auto-repair parks?

Tags: maintenance, repair

I've seen skate parks, dog parks, water parks, bobsled parks, etc.  Are there any auto-repair parks?

I'm picturing something like concrete berms you can drive your car onto to get under it.  Kind of like an auto-repair pit, but you'd be at ground level so no pit to fill with rain.

Most large cities ban car repairs on public roads.  It would be nice if people without a garage had someplace to go to work on their cars.

I'd like to have one built around here.  It would be nice to start with an existing design, learn from the mistakes others have made, what works well and what doesn't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Parks? As in outdoors in the rain, snow or dark? I've never heard of one, but they may exist somewhere.

I've heard of self-service garages that include a lift and access to tools. See a few examples below. I have no connection to any of these businesses.

[Stew's Garage](https://stewsgarage.com/car-lift-rental/)

[Ant's Community Garage](https://www.antscommunitygarage.com/)

[U Wrench It article](https://www.vehicleservicepros.com/shop-operations/article/21270708/ase-master-tech-opens-new-diy-auto-repair-shop-in-new-jersey)

[USA Today article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/money/2015/01/16/self-serve-auto-shops-cater-to-diy-mechanics/21891903/)

Comment: Yes, outdoors.  Legal or not, people wrench on the street and in parking lots all the time.